# DJANGO/Heroku not saving into database POSTGRES

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I am creating an API and my app isn't saving user information to the POSTGRES database. Can someone look over my code and tell me what is wrong?

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['salty-sands-40947.herokuapp.com','.herokuapp.com']
DEBUG = True

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'aroomieapp',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'social_django',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2',
    "push_notifications"
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'aroomie.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                                   'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                   'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                   'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                   'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                                   'django.template.context_processors.media',
                                   'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                                   'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'aroomie.wsgi.application'


# Database

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# Setting the image path in server
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# This package help us to replace our database with Postgresql
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Others auth providers (e.g. Google, OpenId, etc)

    # Facebook OAuth2
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',

    # django-rest-framework-social-oauth2
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',

    # Django
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# Facebook configuration
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = os.environ['FACEBOOK_KEY']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = os.environ['FACEBOOK_SECRET']

# Define SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE to get extra permissions from facebook. Email is not sent by default, to get it, you must request the email permission:
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = [
    'email',
    # 'user_birthday',
]
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id, name, email, age_range, gender'
}

# Login process customization purpose
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'aroomieapp.social_auth_pipeline.extend_user_profile',  # <--- set the path to the function
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

UPDATE (TRACEBACK)

```
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455554+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error: /api/user/profile/
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455575+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455577+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455578+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = get_response(request)
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455579+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455581+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455582+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455583+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455584+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/aroomieapp/apis.py", line 60, in user_get_profile
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455584+00:00 app[web.1]:     expires__gt = timezone.now())
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455585+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455585+00:00 app[web.1]:     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455586+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 385, in get
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455586+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.model._meta.object_name
2017-04-28T00:02:32.455587+00:00 app[web.1]: oauth2_provider.models.DoesNotExist: AccessToken matching query does not exist.
2017-04-28T00:02:32.511548+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/user/profile/?access_token=" host=salty-sands-40947.herokuapp.com request_id=c9c65c38-9617-4616-906f-78cd06dca05c fwd="69.203.1.36" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=97ms status=500 bytes=70045 protocol=https
```

Code with database information:

```
# This package help us to replace our database with Postgresql
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Others auth providers (e.g. Google, OpenId, etc)

     # Facebook OAuth2
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookAppOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',

    # django-rest-framework-social-oauth2
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',

    # Django
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# Facebook configuration
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = os.environ['FACEBOOK_KEY']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = os.environ['FACEBOOK_SECRET']

# Define SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE to get extra permissions from facebook. Email is not sent by default, to get it, you must request the email permission:
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = [
    'email',
    # 'user_birthday',
]
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id, name, email, age_range, gender'
}

# Login process customization purpose
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'aroomieapp.social_auth_pipeline.extend_user_profile',  # <--- set the path to the function
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

social_auth_pipeline:

```
from aroomieapp.models import Profile

def extend_user_profile(backend, user, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.name == 'facebook':
        avatar = 'https://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=normal' % response['id']
        gender = response['gender']
        age_min = response['age_range']['min'] if response['age_range'].get('min') else 0
        age_max = response['age_range']['max'] if response['age_range'].get('max') else 0
        lifestyle_info = "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"

        if not Profile.objects.filter(user_id=user.id):
            Profile.objects.create(user_id=user.id, age_min=age_min, age_max=age_max, gender=gender, avatar=avatar, lifestyle_info=lifestyle_info)
```

I am also getting an AccessToken error message when it tries to create one. I really am stuck and I do not know where to go from here.

Thank you

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your settings. Can you post your full traceback please?

Comment: @ChidG I have updated the post with the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. It had to do with the creation of my client_id and client_secret tokens. Sometimes the Heroku generated client_id and client_secret tokens aren't generated. So what you have to do to work around this is to go into your django admin and create a new application. With the following settings:
Client type: confidential or public
Authorization grant type: Authorization code
Name: Name of service (in my case Facebook)

This will give you the client_id and client_secret tokens but they will ONLY work if you click submit to create the application. Once that is done, your API will be able to communicate with your application.

Answer (score 1):

Your settings don't mention PostgresSQL. They only specify a sqlite3 database.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

You should follow the [instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#provision-a-database) and add:

```
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
...
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Comment: Right. Then can you include the actual code that updates the database?

Comment: Yes I updated it now. Also when I do a curl request to revoke-token, it keeps telling me that my client_id parameter is invalid. Could it be that?

Comment: That's just the config again. What do OAuth and all the tokens have to do with not being able to write to the database?

Comment: I do not know. I am just cloning someone's git. Do you want to take a look at the git files instead so they can give you a better understanding of what is going on? [link](https://github.com/yongching/ARoomie-API)